# Rest call requires JSESSIONID (Spring boot, Spring Security, OAuth2, Zuul)

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have two spring-boot processes.  I have Spring Security enabled on both, and I'm using Spring Security OAuth2 SSO setup.  I'm also using Eureka and Zuul to allows calls into Boot1 to call into services in Boot2.  UI is using Angular with REST calls into the services, and the token being used is a Json Web Token.

This all seems to work, certainly in the UI.  All the requests use the Authorization header (which contains the JWT) and the spring security filter in the services successfully parse the JWT and extracts the Security Context from it.  As part of the Spring Web processing, it adds a JSESSIONID value to the client's cookie.

Recently, I only had Spring security on Boot1.  When calling rest services into Boot1, which end up using Zuul to forward requests to Boot2, all I required in the rest client was to include the Authorization header with the JWT and it all worked fine.

However, I have recently added Spring Security to Boot2 (using the @EnableResourceServer annotation) and now rest calls fail unless I have both the Authorization header as well as a Cookie header that contains a JSESSIONID value.  Calls don't fail, but they return empty values.

I've enabled logging to Spring Security, and it validates all correctly in Boot1.  It's going into the same ZuulFilter.  But there's no activity on Boot2.

Is there something in Zuul that requires a JSESSIONID value to be defined in order for it forward the request?  Or is this in Boot2, where it is expecting a JSESSIONID header value due to the introduction of Spring Security filters?

--- update ---

I've stepped through boot1.  From what I can see, code in the OAuth2TokenRelayFilter is throwing an exception.  Specifically, the method getAccessToken is calling restTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue (line 90, version 1.1.0-RELEASE) which throws a UserRedirectRequiredException.

So, while the TokenRelayFilter has a token, it's attempting to refresh it.  When it receives an exception, it's throwing a BadCredentialsException instead of using what's already been defined.

--- update 2 ---

Putting a breakpoint in OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration, making rest calls without the JSESSIONID always ends up with a new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext to be created, as it's trying to create session-scoped beans.  With the JSESSIONID, it's using a persisted DefaultOAuth2ClientContext, which will have the context.

So, is it possible to, when constructing the DefaultOAuth2ClientContext, to see if the request contains the token and uses it?  Or something like this?  We're trying to move to stateless services, and this seems to be a hurdle towards this.

Comment: How does your Angular UI get hold of JWT token issued by your Oauth2 server and how does it presented to Boot2 app while using Angularjs $http? I have raised a question of related tutorial project.
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/issues/114

Comment: What I trying to achieve - UI App  - a @ EnableSSO app , once authenticated can do $http calls to Boot[n] app that is @ EnableResourceServer - uses the JWT token for auth . Without using zuul proxy ( once I have taken care of cross origin)

Comment: The client UI, after logging in, calls Spring's /user endpoint to get details about the user.  Which includes the JWT.  All subsequent calls to the Rest endpoints pass the JWT as part of the HTTP Header "Authorization".  For us, we want to use the Zuul proxy, as it reduces the attack vector on our application.  However, now that we have security on both processes, it does work regardless of which resource server we end up calling within the javascript.

Comment: So you must be saving the JWT token as Cookie right  after getting it from /user endpoint right ? I am puzzled because the 'oauth2' sample project  in mentioned github project doesn't seems to be storing JWT anywhere client side but still able to fetch data from the jwt protected 'resource' server.

Comment: We've stored the token in a cookie.  We've also used local storage.   We have noticed that if you use JSESSIONIDs in the header, the Spring Security contexts will be tracked against the JSESSION, and that will have the JWT context as part of that.  We found that when we were using web apps against our services.  Where it started to come apart was when we were calling into our REST services from tablet applications (or other clients not running within the browser) where we needed to ensure we have the token embedded in the header.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the client-id values used by the different parts of the system.

Looking at OAuth2TokenRelayFilter, it is attempting to refresh the token if the client-id defined for the resource server (boot1) matches that which is defined as part of the token contained within the token provided with the request.  In my case, this was true: the token was defined using the same client-id.

That really is not correct.  When I update my rest client to use a token, but using a different client-id when requesting the token, then the request is forwarded correctly as expected, without the need for a jsessionid.  This is exactly what I want.

I suspect that this was caused, in the end, by incorrect use of client-id values by the components of my system.